# Wireshark - ignore all packages captured so far

Tags: wireshark

Lets say I start capturing and wait for a minute. How can I ignore all packages captured in that time so that similar packages are not showing anymore.

I need this to filter out the "boring" standard traffic e.g. Broadcasts, so that I can listen for my target.

Is this possible with wireshark? If not, is there better software which can do this? There is just too much noise and I have no time to filter it out one by one manually.

Comment: https://wiki.wireshark.org/DuplicatePackets

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382855/removing-duplicate-packets-from-pcap

Comment: @CaldeiraG, thats not related to my question.

Comment: To ignore broadcasts, you could use the filter `(not eth.dst == ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff && eth.ig==0) && (not eth.addr == 33:33:00:01:00:02 && eth.ig==0) `.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. I think it only works by writing a plugin:
https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development